# How do i make a gantt chart with multiple date entry fields that change the colour of the chart with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, windows, excel-formula

I need to make a Gantt chart in excel using conditional formatting.

Basically the chart is plotting anticipated start and end dates against tasks.  I need it to also plot actual start and end dates on the same row.

Currently i have the cells change to grey that lie within the anticipated start and end dates.

The part i cant figure out is if the 'actual start date' is more than the 'Expected start date' then all the cells previous to the 'actual start date' in the calendar need to be red (To show how late the task was started) and then once the task is started all the cells after the 'actual start date' i need to be green.

[image: Example of Current Gantt Chart.]

Thanks

Comment: Conditional formatting works in order of priority, so the formatting highest on the list will override anything below it. So you should be able to just write another couple of conditional formatting rules and put them higher up on the list.

Comment: I have not tried, but would making three series work each with the colour you need? Separate by their date...

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, i ended up doing what Jacob said and it worked.